# ClassCastException OracleSQLXML / XMLType when reading XML from Oracle DB

Tags: xml, spring, oracle, spring-data

I have some XML document that is stored in my Oracle DB as a Blob, that I'm trying to read from Spring Batch.

I followed some tutorials that I found here and there (quite a struggle to get the right jars, not properly versionned, from Oracle), but now I'm facing a clear exception when running my code :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLXML cannot be cast to oracle.xdb.XMLType
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.OracleXmlHandler.getXmlAsString(OracleXmlHandler.java:45) ~[spring-data-oracle-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I've checked my dependencies, it seems to be OK.

Any idea where that could come from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we need to set an environment property so that return type matches the expectations :

```
System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.getObjectReturnsXMLType", "true");
```

This only made it work for me !